# Using multiple tickers in R

Tags: r

I'm am trying to load multiple tickers in R and I keep getting the error "auto.assign=TRUE", but I don't know where to put it... Below is my code

```
library(zoo)
library(tseries)
library(fBasics)

quote = "AdjClose"
start = "2013-01-01"
end = "2015-12-31"
compression = "d"
retclass = "zoo"
provider = "yahoo"
origin = "1970-01-01"
ticker = c("aapl", "ebay", "goog","bbby")
```

I think I'm doing something wrong with my Prices...

```
Prices = get.hist.quote(instrument = ticker, start = start, 
         end = end, quote = quote, provider = provider,
         origin = origin, compression = compression, 
         retclass = retclass)
```

I tried added a loop...

```
for(ticker in c("aapl", "ebay", "goog", "bbby")){
Prices = get.hist.quote(instrument = ticker, start = start,
                        end = end,quote = quote, provider = provider,
                        origin = origin, compression = compression, 
 retclass = retclass)}
```

But when I print out the prices, it only does the last tracker. It's overwritting the the 1st ticker with the 2nd and the 2nd with the 3rd and the 3 with the 4th. How can I get it to print out all prices for each different ticker?

Answer (score 0):

The instrument has to be "a character string giving the name of the quote symbol to download". Try looping over your four tickers.

It only does the last ticker because your loop is overwriting Prices. Maybe you will find your answers [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/pass-character-vector-in-instrument-field-of-get-hist-quote-function-td3350779.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list to store the different `zoo` series:

```
Price <- list()
for(ticker in c("aapl", "ebay", "goog", "bbby")){
  Price[[ticker]] <- get.hist.quote(instrument = ticker, start = start,
                          end = end,quote = quote, provider = provider,
                          origin = origin, compression = compression, 
                          retclass = retclass)
}
```

This will allow you to access the series of the individual tickers, like `Price$aapl`.